# Visual Studio IDE - keybinding for multicommands

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, key-bindings

To generate a vertical split in the editor window, the suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/split-editor-vertically/380955#T-N527726) works. Can this sequence of commands:

1. Window->New Window
2. Window->New Vertical Document Group

be assigned a single keybinding?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following command in my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.NewWindow");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.NewVerticalTabGroup");
}
```

and assign a shortcut to it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I use multi-command extension in VS Code for this and I was wondering if something similar was available under Visual Studio. I will try it out later today and update the answer acceptance status at that time.